# Tridion GateWay timeout errors while previewing navigation file

Tags: cme, 2013-sp1

When i try to preview any navigation file which has many structuregroups in the publication , it results in gateway time our error.

I have run a Fiddler trace and found that any response which is taking more than 59 seconds is resulting in Gateway timeout errors.

This happens also while publishing,listing,rendering etc.

```
/WebUI/Models/TCM54/Services/Rendering.svc/Preview failed to execute. STATUS (504): Gateway Time-out
```

I have verified all my configuration files and they seem to be updated with proper timings.[image]

Comment: What Template model are you using, and if it is Modular Templating, does it run in the Template Builder and how long does it take in there?

Comment: Can you possibly include snippets from your configuration files for us to also review, although as David indicates in his answer this is more likely to be IIS or network device related

Comment: In the template builder it approximately takes 2 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite common to see with pages or components that take a long time to preview, such as sitemaps. It is not the Tridion rendering service that is timing out, but either IIS or some other network device in between you and Tridion is enforcing a 1 minute timeout on the http request.

Comment: Thanks David, The issue is found to be with the Akamai configuration .the domain was akamaized and the default timeout was set on it to two minutes.

Comment: Indeed It works. Also if you are using AWS, make sure your idle timeout on ELB is increased to have it working.